# DHCP address leases to SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, dhcp

Is it possible to store the DHCP address leases in Windows 2003 to SQL Server database??

Answer (score 1):

No. Point.DHCP is independant of SQL Server and there is no provvision. You can always use the DNS api to retrieve the DNS entries or the server management API to retrieve the assignments, but you must code this bridge yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659:

> Log parser is a powerful, versatile tool that provides universal query
>   access to text-based data such as log files, XML files and CSV files,
>   as well as key data sources on the Windows® operating system such as
>   the Event Log, the Registry, the file system, and Active Directory®.
>   You tell Log Parser what information you need and how you want it
>   processed. The results of your query can be custom-formatted in text
>   based output, or they can be persisted to more specialty targets like
>   SQL, SYSLOG, or a chart.